# backup Sql Databases from file system

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Background:
I m using a SharePoint 2010, and now i have to change my window. what i want is to take a backup of all databases of my SharePoint instance of SQ L server 2008.
I have searched, but all methods are proper traditional, that is taking backup from sq l management studio.

Problem:
Actually i have not much time to backup each database, what i want is to copy that folder(contains SQ L databases) from C:\ . i want a copy of all databases saved.

Question
Is there any way to get all backups on one copy past ?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use the windows Volume Shadow Service to make a snapshot of your C drive. If SQL Server is properly set up, that should also ensure that the database files are in a consistent state.

You can then just copy the necessary files over.

You may also want to have a look at my greenclone program ( open source and compiled binaries available through https://bitbucket.org/bilkusg/greenclone ) which can take a shadow copy and duplicate any desired directory hierarchy on windows.

If you adopt this approach, do please test restoring your data somehow before relying on it for a production system!